# Clearing all elements from all arbitrary lists of sublists in python

Tags: python, iterator

Assume we have a list that looks like this:

```
L = [0, 1, [2, [3, 4], 5], [6, 7]]
```

What would be the best way to clear out all the elements from each sublist without removing the sublists? For example, in this case the return value would be:

```
>>> clearsublists(L)
[[[]], []]
```

EDIT: There are ways of doing this using wonky string methods like converting the list to a string and counting the number of times the symbols '[', '(' and '{' appear, but that would screw up if you have a list of deques for example, as a deque would be displayed as deque([]), making the program think there are actually two subsets when it's really only one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For arbitrary depth, use recursion:

```
def clearsublists(L):
    return [clearsublists(l) for l in L if isinstance(l, list)]
```

Comment: Of course, should've thought about recursive methods before I asked the question. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Definitely the most elegant solution. +1.

Answer (score 2):

```
def clear(L):
    if not L:
        return []
    else:
        return [clear(i) for i in L if isinstance(i, list)]
```

Output:

```
>>> L = [0, 1, [2, [3, 4], 5], [6, 7]]
>>> clear(L)
[[[]], []]
```